# Running a container, returns error code 127 when asking for logs from another container

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am relatively new to these kinds of things, both docker and stack overflow, so please feel free to let me know if there is something other than the code I am doing wrong.

My setup s basically that I have one 'file system' which is ready to be built into a container, and then separately I have this container (https://github.com/itzg/docker-minecraft-server) running a mc server. The general idea behind what I am doing is that my first code, when it receives a message from discord, starts my second code, which then starts the mc container, and looks through the logs for a message containing "joined the game" or "left the game". It keeps track of this, thus knowing how many people are on the server, and then after a period of time of inactivity, (0 players on the server) will shut down the server, to save on resources. What is quite weird to me is that the code runs perfectly when it is not in a container, so rather than building the container, I just go to the directory and run "python3 discord_surveyor.py"

I am not aware if there are any official methods of doing this, but the idea behind this was that I wanted to make it, so while I will appreciate suggestions, I most likely wont use them.

The codes are as following
**First code (discord surveyor)**

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import subprocess

command = 'python3 ./read.py'

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
        print('=')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('/startmc'):
            await message.channel.send('Attempting to start Minecraft server...')
            print('Attempting to start Minecraft Server')

            # Try to start the server
            try:
                process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
                await asyncio.sleep(3)

                # Check if the server is still running
                if process.poll() is None:
                    await message.channel.send('Minecraft server started successfully!')
                else:
                    await message.channel.send('Failed to start Minecraft server.')
            except Exception as e:
                await message.channel.send(f'Error starting Minecraft server: {str(e)}')

            await asyncio.sleep(3)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('MTIwMTA1Nzk3ODk1MDg4MTMxMQ.GdOLzD.94oOLKFThHyva6msBRlT5Pvzm3ZilACxXdNzEs')
```

**Second Code (Docker_control) - called read.py**

```
import subprocess
import datetime
import time
import signal
from multiprocessing import Process

# Adjustable variables
container_name = "mcj_server_mc_1"
filter_strings = ["joined the game", "left the game"]
zero_duration_threshold = 15 * 60  # 60 seconds

def start_docker_container(container):
    try:
        subprocess.run(f"docker start {container}", shell=True, check=True)
        print(f"Docker container '{container}' started successfully.")
        time.sleep(5)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error starting Docker container: {e}")

def stop_docker_container(container):
    try:
        subprocess.run(f"docker stop {container}", shell=True, check=True)
        print(f"Docker container '{container}' stopped successfully.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error stopping Docker container: {e}")

def read_last_second_logs(container):
    players = 0
    zero_duration = 0
    zero_timer_start = None

    def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print("Exiting... Stopping Docker container.")
        stop_docker_container(container)
        exit(0)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    while True:
        try:
            start_time = time.time()  # Record the start time

            # Calculate the timestamp for the past second
            past_second = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
            timestamp = past_second.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

            # Use subprocess to run the docker logs command with time filtering
            command = f"docker logs --since {timestamp} {container}"
            result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
            if result.stdout:
              print('Log_Check_OK')
            else:
              print("No logs found!")
            # Process logs and update the 'players' count
            for line in result.stdout.split('\n'):
                if any(filter_str in line for filter_str in filter_strings):
                    if filter_strings[0] in line:
                        players += 1
                    elif filter_strings[1] in line:
                        players -= 1

            # Print the current players count
            print(f"Players count: {players}")

            # Check if players count is 0
            if players == 0:
                if zero_timer_start is None:
                    zero_timer_start = time.time()

                zero_duration = time.time() - zero_timer_start
                if zero_duration >= zero_duration_threshold:
                    # Execute the stop command if zero duration is greater than or equal to 60 seconds
                    stop_docker_container(container)
                    print("Docker inactive")
                    break
                else:
                    # Print the zero duration
                    print(f"Zero duration: {zero_duration:.2f} seconds")

            else:
                # Reset the zero timer if players count is non-zero
                zero_timer_start = None

            end_time = time.time()  # Record the end time
            execution_time = end_time - start_time
            print(f"Execution time: {execution_time:.2f} seconds")

            # Sleep for one second before running the next iteration
            sleep_duration = max(0, 1 - execution_time)
            time.sleep(sleep_duration)

        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            # Handle error if the docker logs command fails
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            print(f"Command Output: {e.output}")

def run_monitoring_in_background(container):
    process = Process(target=read_last_second_logs, args=(container,))
    process.start()
    process.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Check if the container is already running
    existing_containers = subprocess.run(f"docker ps -q --filter name={container_name}", shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip()

    if not existing_containers:
        # Start the Docker container
        start_docker_container(container_name)
        print("Monitoring process started in the background.")
    else:
        print(f"Docker container '{container_name}' is already running.")

    # Run monitoring process in the background
    run_monitoring_in_background(container_name)
```

I tried all sort to fix it, as pre mentioned, ran fine with same codes when it was outisde of a docker, but can't remain like that because both it takeds up my terminal and wont auto restart the needed codes if it crashes.I tried networking the containers, still doesn't work.

Comment: The Docker SDK for Python has a [`container.logs()` method](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.logs) that can get a container's logs, as a non-blocking stream, without stopping it.  Would that be easier to use?  (Note, you should pretty much never use the `shell=True` option.  What happens if `container_name` is set to `anything; rm a_file;`?)

Comment: Thanks for the help, tried to implement this, seems to have done something cos now I am getting a different error. Dunno if I have implemented it wrong, or something but ill paste the error code down below, and the section of the code which I changed.

Comment: Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./read.py", line 49, in read_last_second_logs
    result = container.logs(stream=True, tail=10)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'logs'


            result = container.logs(stream=True, tail=10)
            for log_line in logs_stream:

Comment: wouldnt let me post allthe code :/

Comment: You got the above error because you use only the name of the container (as string), but you have to use a Container object. As documentation says: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. Like:
`import docker;
client = docker.from_env();
container = client.containers.get("<Your container ID/Name>");
print(container.logs())
`